# how to Extract multiple OU name using Powershell's Get-ADOrganizationUnit & Get-ADComputer

Tags: powershell

In AD hostnames are created under location OU, inside location OU under computer sub OU. i
need a script to extract both OU in excel. i am able to extract one OU details through below scrpit

```
Get-ADComputer -filter * -Properties ipv4Address, OperatingSystem,DistinguishedName |
    select-object Name, ipv4Address, OperatingSystem,
        @{label='OU';expression={$_.DistinguishedName.Split(',')[1].Split('=')[1]}}
```

i need help to extract main OU details please help

Answer (score 1):

If you want all OUs in the path, you can use a regex pattern to extract them.

```
[regex]$pattern = '(?<=OU=)(.+?)(?=,\w{2}=)'

$searchbase = 'OU=Company,DC=Domain,DC=LOCAL'

$properties = 'Name',
              'ipv4Address',
              'OperatingSystem',
              @{n='OU';e={$pattern.Matches($_.DistinguishedName).Value -join ', '}}

$adparams = @{
    Filter     = '*'
    Searchbase = $searchbase
    Properties = 'ipv4Address',
                 'OperatingSystem'
}

Get-ADComputer @adparams |
    Select-Object $properties
```

If you're after just the OU above computers, then something like this may work.

```
[regex]$pattern = '(?<=OU=)(.+?)(?=,\w{2}=)'

$searchbase = 'OU=Company,DC=Domain,DC=LOCAL'

$properties = 'Name',
              'ipv4Address',
              'OperatingSystem',
              @{n='OUs';e={$pattern.Matches($_.DistinguishedName)[1].Value}}

$adparams = @{
    Filter     = '*'
    Searchbase = $searchbase
    Properties = 'ipv4Address',
                 'OperatingSystem'
}

Get-ADComputer @adparams |
    Select-Object $properties
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This script worked as expected but i have few more query when i extract the data all the OU details are coming in same column (SERVERS, COMPUTERS, DLF) but i need that is different columns how to split the data can you please help me